# PSQL Is this a legal way to use subqueries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, subquery

I'm studying for my exam in Database Management Systems and there's something I'm not really sure, whether it's legal or not.

In a database of a club, I'm asked to return the name, email and amount (to pay per year).

- If a person is a "SinglePerson" the amount is 20.--,
- if it's an organisation, the amount is 150.--

The database looks like this:

```
Table Membership
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    email text NOT NULL,
    ... --unnecessary
)

Table Organisation
(
    id int REFERENCES Membership(id) PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar Not NULL
    ... -- unnecessary
)

Table SinglePerson
(
    id int REFERENCES Membership(id) PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar NOT NULL
)
```

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    Name, Email, Amount
FROM
    (SELECT 
         E.Name, M.Email, 20 AS Amount
     FROM 
         SinglePerson AS E
     JOIN 
         Membership As M ON M.Id = E.Id),
    (SELECT 
         O.Name, M.Email, 150 AS Amount
     FROM 
         Organisation AS O
     JOIN 
         Membership AS M ON M.Id = O.Id);
```

Is this query possible?

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are no laws about subqueries -- just syntax errors.  But there should be a law forbidding commas in `FROM` clauses.  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Although I would write the query differently, you seem to be aiming for a `UNION ALL` type of query:

```
SELECT sp.Name, M.Email, 20 AS Amount
FROM SinglePerson sp JOIN
     Membership M
     ON M.Id = sp.Id
UNION ALL
SELECT O.Name, M.Email, 150 AS Amount
FROM Organisation O JOIN
     Membership M
     ON M.Id = O.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
select
  m.name,
  m.email,
  case when s.id is not null then 20
       when o.id is not null then 150
       else null
  end as amount
from membership m
left join singleperson s on s.id = m.id
left join organisation o on o.id = m.id
```